# Websocket functionality in Opera

Tags: websocket, opera

I am trying to learn about websocket functionality supported by Opera browser. I got some sample code from web.

Is it possible to connect to a simple c echo server (not using web server) serving on some port (say 9999) from Opera 12.x browser using websockets? I tried this but is not working. I am getting disconnected error in browser with ERROR: undefined. At Linux echo server side, it is getting a connect request, accepting it, but not able to read any data.

I am loading the test page locally not from any web server.

If simple echo server is not sufficient, is it possible to enhance the simple echo server to return HTTP response and make it work. Basically I am trying to use websockets interfaces from browser to connect to a server without using any web server.

Thanks,
raj

websocket client (Copied from http://www.websocket.org/echo.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

 <meta charset="utf-8" /> 

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

  var wsUri = "ws://192.168.100.2:9999/"; 
 var output; 

  function init() 
 { 
 output = document.getElementById("output"); 
 testWebSocket(); 
 } 

  function testWebSocket() 
 { 
 websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 
 websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) }; 
 websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) }; 
 websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) }; 
 websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) }; 
 } 

  function onOpen(evt) 
 { 
 writeToScreen("CONNECTED"); 
 doSend("WebSocket rocks"); 
 } 

  function onClose(evt) 
 { 
 writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED"); 
 } 

  function onMessage(evt) 
 { 
 writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>'); 
 websocket.close(); 
 } 

  function onError(evt) 
 { 
 writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data); 
 } 

  function doSend(message) 
 { 
 writeToScreen("SENT: " + message); 
 websocket.send(message); 
 } 

  function writeToScreen(message) 
 { 
 var pre = document.createElement("p"); 
 pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word"; 
 pre.innerHTML = message; 
 output.appendChild(pre); 
 } 

  window.addEventListener("load", init, false); 

 </script> 

 <div id="output"></div> 

 </html>
```

Echo Server(copied from http://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/sockets/programs/part2/chap6/simple-server.c)
.

```
.

#define MY_PORT     9999
#define MAXBUF      1024

int main(int Count, char *Strings[])
{   int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in self;
    char buffer[MAXBUF];

    /*---Create streaming socket---*/
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(errno);
    }

    /*---Initialize address/port structure---*/
    bzero(&self, sizeof(self));
    self.sin_family = AF_INET;
    self.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT);
    self.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    /*---Assign a port number to the socket---*/
    if ( bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&self, sizeof(self)) != 0 )
    {
        perror("socket--bind");
        exit(errno);
    }

    /*---Make it a "listening socket"---*/
    if ( listen(sockfd, 20) != 0 )
    {
        perror("socket--listen");
        exit(errno);
    }

    /*---Forever... ---*/
    while (1)
    {   int clientfd;
        struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
        int addrlen=sizeof(client_addr);

        /*---accept a connection (creating a data pipe)---*/
        clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen);
        printf("%s:%d connected\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
        printf("Received %d\n", recv(clientfd, buffer, MAXBUF, 0));
        printf("Date %s\n\n", buffer);


        /*---Echo back anything sent---*/
        send(clientfd, buffer, recv(clientfd, buffer, MAXBUF, 0), 0);

        /*---Close data connection---*/
        close(clientfd);
    }
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WebSocket protocol is not a raw TCP socket connection. You're server must also support the WebSocket protocol.

There is a online WebSockets echo service at http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

If you really want to connect from WebSockets to a raw socket server you can use [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) to bridge between the two. **Disclaimer**: I made websockify.